# Get current user inside getData of Datastudio community connector

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

Trying to dev a [community connector for Datastudio](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/), I'd like to retrieve, from my `getData` function, the user currently using the report (not the creator of the report).

When I log the `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` or `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`, it is not the name of the user. I tried setting auth mode to NONE or OAUTH2: same result.

Any idea if that's possible?

Comment: Did you use `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`? You're only able to acquire the email address of the user. If you don't use `.getEmail()` you log the object, which might be logged in unreadable form. [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user)

Comment: Yes I'm logging `getEmail()` and it's always my email logged (I'm the dev of the Datastudio report, as well as the dev of the connector, but I'm not the end user of the report...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data source is using [Owner's credentials](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6371135?hl=en), [`Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser()) will give you the data source owner's (i.e. creator) email address. If someone else views the report, you cannot get their identity in the connector.

If the data source is using [Viewer's credentials](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6371135?hl=en), [`Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getEffectiveUser()) will give you the viewer's identity. However, with *Viewer's credentials*, the viewer will have to authorize the connector first. Otherwise viewers will see error when they view the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer but a way to help on solving this question. When you check scope authorization in the user account for the data source, we can see the userinfo.email scope validated, good point.

If you are in testing mode (step 13 in this code lab for example https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/community-connectors) if you add the Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail() in a console.log for the getData() function you will get user email. 
=> For that as you are in testing mode you have to share the script code in read only for anyone with the link.
If the script is not shared you will not get email and generate an error when you try to access community connector.

The question now is to know if once the connector is published if you still need to keep you file shared publicly with anyone with the link.
My guess is not.