# Appscript detect Google Data Studio user session

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have a data studio report that will show different data based on different users. I developed appscript and expose it as Community Connector so that I can control type of data to return back to data studio.

In my appscript, I'm using Session.getActiveUser() to track the current user. When I tried to open up the data studio report link using different gmail account, my appscript log shows that Session.getActiveUser() always returns the same email.

I even deployed the appscript as

- Web APP > execute as user accessing the app
- Add On
- Library

How can appscript Session.getActiveUser() can return detect the current user who is access the data studio report link? Or is it the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you'll need to use Session.getEffectiveUser to determine the user's identity.
https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/blocks/user-identity

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52884127) also describes what to expect depending of if the data source is set to 'Owner's credentials' or 'Viewer's credentials'